# Showing that intensive parameters obtain by considering molar quantities

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, differentiation

In Callen's Thermodynamics textbook, he writes that
$$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\right)_v = \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N}$$

where $u = U/N$, $s = s/N$, and $v = V/N$ and, moreover, $U$ is first order homogeneous so that
$$ U (S,V,N) = U(SN/N,VN/N,N) = NU(S/N,V/N,1) \equiv Nu(s,v)$$
where the last equality represents another way to define $u$. I'm not able to see how to argue for the given equality of derivatives though. I get stalled out:
$$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\right)_v \equiv \left(\frac{\partial (U/N)}{\partial (S/N)}\right)_{V/N} \stackrel{?}{=} \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N}$$

I want to be clear that I understand why (namely because the quantity so obtained on the RHS is intensive) this equality must hold, but I can't see how to show it mathematically as I get lost in the morass of partial derivatives and chain rules.

Comment: It might be easier to go in the other direction.

Comment: @Chemomechanics I will try that right now; one moment!

Comment: @Chemomechanics I see it now, thank you! Note to self -- try both ways in the future :)

Comment: @EE18 Calculus works both ways: $$
   \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\right)_v 
   \equiv 
   \left(\frac{\partial (U/N)}{\partial (S/N)}\right)_{V/N} 
   = 
   \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N}
$$ With $N=\text{const}$ we go from the middle result to the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that
$$ \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N} \equiv \left(\frac{\partial (Nu(S/N,V/N))}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N} = N\left(\frac{\partial (u(S/N,V/N))}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N}  $$
$$\stackrel{(1)}{=} N \left[\left(\frac{\partial (u(S/N,V/N))}{\partial (S/N)}\right)_{V/N}\left(\frac{\partial (S/N)}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N} + \left(\frac{\partial (u(S/N,V/N))}{\partial (V/N)}\right)_{S/N}\left(\frac{\partial (V/N)}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N} \right]$$
$$ N \left[\left(\frac{\partial (u(S/N,V/N))}{\partial (S/N)}\right)_{V/N}\frac{1}{N} + 0 \right] = \left(\frac{\partial (u(S/N,V/N))}{\partial (S/N)}\right)_{V/N}$$
$$\equiv \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\right)_v $$
where in (1) we have used the chain rule for partial derivatives and in the last step we have simply used the definitions of $s$ and $v$.

Answer (score 1):

The key point here is the *homogeneity* of extensive thermodynamic properties. For $U(S,V,N)$ this means that if we increase $S$, $V$, $N$, simultaneously by the same factor, then $U$ increases by the same factor as well:
$$
   U(\lambda S, \lambda V, \lambda N) = \lambda U(S,V,N)
$$
It follows that the partial derivatives of $U$ are intensive. This can be shown by calculus for any homogeneous function with degree 1 but in this case it is clear since these derivatives are known intensive properties:
$$
     \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{VN} = T;\quad
     \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_{VN} = -P;\quad
     \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{VN} = \mu.
$$
As intensive properties they do not depend on the absolute $U$, $V$ and $N$, but have the same value in all systems with the same *ratios* $S:V:N$. Therefore, they have the same values in a system with $s=S/N$, $v=V/N$, $n=N/N=1$:
$$
   \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{VN} =
   \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\right)_{v} = T.
$$

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the very simple and immediate proof based on the definition of the partial derivative and the homogeneity of $U$:
$$
\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N} = \lim_{\Delta S \rightarrow 0} \frac{U(S+\Delta S,V,N)-U(S,V,N)}{\Delta S}=\lim_{\Delta s \rightarrow 0} \frac{U(N s+ N \Delta s,N v,N)-U(N s,N v,N)}{N\Delta s}=
\lim_{\Delta s \rightarrow 0} \frac{u(s+\Delta s,v)-u(s,v)}{\Delta s}=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial u}\right)_{v}
$$