# Is it possible to deduce the chemical potential from a molar fundamental equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy, definition

In Callen, it's shown that for a simple system, the entropy can be written as $U(V,S,N) = Nu(v,s)$ where $s = S/N$ and $v = V/N$. One can then prove (as I asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/763314/showing-that-intensive-parameters-obtain-by-considering-molar-quantities)) that both the temperature and the pressure can be obtained by corresponding derivatives of the molar function $u$:
$$T := \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N} = \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\right)_v$$
$$-P := \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_{S,N} = \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}\right)_s.$$
My question is, is there a similar relationship that can allow me to deduce $\mu := \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial N}\right)_{S,V}$. That is, can I take a derivative of $u$ somehow can so obtain $\mu$? Or is the conclusion that the chemical potential is not fixed when aper-mole relationship is given?

I can compute
$$\mu := \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial N}\right)_{S,V} = \left(\frac{\partial (uN)}{\partial N}\right)_{S,V} = u +N\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial N}\right)_{S,V} = u+N\left[\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\right)_v\left(\frac{\partial s}{\partial N}\right)_{S,V} + \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}\right)_v\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial N}\right)_{S,V}\right]$$
$$ = u +N \left[-T\frac{S}{N^2} +P\frac{V}{N^2} \right] = u -sT+Pv.$$
I suppose this is something I can deduce from the molar fundamental equation $u$, if my work is correct? But it seems odd that I could have information conjugate to the number of particles (or moles) $N$ in the system without even "using" $N$ (since that doesn't appear in $u$)?

Comment: It ain't molar, but rather "per total number of particles", and I suspect you already know that. And no, the reason why Callen had to derive it that way, is that if you do not first reason out this scaling relationship and tried instead to derive it another way, you will derive a wrong version of Sackur-Tetrode entropy formula that is not linear in N, and thus the chemical potential will be wrong. You use Callen's derivation to get Sackur-Tetrode correctly first, and then reinstate the N, and differentiate to get $\mu$ correctly.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I'm not sure I follow, would you be able to flesh that out? I'm not sure I already know whatever you're talking about? $N$ is the number of moles in Callen, but it's clear that we can relate this to number of particles using Avogadro's number.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Are you saying that my derivation is correct here? Callen hasn't given this derivation (yet?) so I'm not sure.

Comment: Callen might be using the wrong words. It has been a decade since I last rigorously studied that wonderful book. But nobody in physics really work with molar quantities $n$, because we all know that it is $N$ that is the thing to care about. I think your derivation is correct, but it is probably considered trivial because the aim of Callen is to get the correct answer, and he had already gotten enough to get $\mu$ correctly without making your manipulations.

Comment: To add to the comment by @naturallyInconsistent: "nobody in physics really work with molar quantities" -- That's a very good point and needs to be emhasized. Consider a binary mixture, then $U$ is a function of four independent variables, $S$, $V$, $N_1$ and $N_2$. The molar property $u$ however is a function of *three* variables, $s$, $v$, and one of the two mol fractions but not both, since $x_1+x_2=1$. So, the typical workflow is to work with *extensive* variables where all $N_i$ are independent, then translate the final result into molar if you have to.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, is there a similar relationship that can allow me to deduce $\mu := \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial N}\right)_{S,V}$.

Yes. The differential of $U(S,V,N)$ is
$$\tag{1}
   dU = T dS - P dV + \mu dN,
$$
and the chemical potential is indeed the partial derivative of $U$ wrt $N$ at constant $S$ and $V$.

To show that the above relationship is consistent with other known relationships we integrate at fixed $T$, $P$ and $\mu$, which gives
$$
   U = T S - P V + \mu N
$$
With $\mu N = G$, this becomes
$$
   G = U - T S + P V .
$$
To deduce the relationship between the chemical potential and internal energy, write
$$
\tag{2}
   dU = 
   \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N} dS +
   \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_{S,N} dV +
   \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial N}\right)_{S,V} dN
$$
and compare with Eq (1).

Of course, what counts as "deducing" depends on what one takes as definitions. I like to think of (1) as the starting point ("fundamental differential") from where all other relationships follow. In this view, the relationship$\mu := \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial N}\right)_{S,V}$ is the definition of $\mu$, while $G=\mu N$ becomes a derived result.

Comment: That it becomes a derived result follows because $G = U - T S + P V .$ is itself a definition (of $G$)?

Comment: Yes: $\mu N = U - T S + P V = G$ follows from the two unnumbered equations in my response, the first of which is a result of (1) and the second of which is the definition of $G$.